Make a table in PowerBI based on multiple selections in another table
I have the following table, correlating people with activities:



Name
Age
Cyclist
Canoeist
Hiker
Runner




Bill
45
X

X
X


Susie
28

X




Fred
33
X
X




Thys
28

X
X



Lin
67


X
X



I wish to have a table showing the names and ages, where the user can select one or multiple activities.
For instance, someone can select "Hiker" and the table will show Bill, Thys, and Lin.  If they select "Hiker" and "Runner", they get Bill & Lin.
I am not sure how to do this.  I am open to suggestions on how to structure the data table to make this possible.
I can drag the individual activity columns in as filters for the visual, but I want something that's easier for end users.

just use matrix mode, not table.

When loading the data into PBI, I changed X to 1 and empty values to 0.
Then based on the Cyclist, Canoeist, Hiker and Runner columns, I unpivoted the data in PQ :


Then keep only the rows where Participates = 1 :

The full PQ code :
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcsrMyVHSUTIxBRKGQGwApQ2VYnWilYJLizNTgTwjCyQpAzAGSbsVpaYAOcbGcE3IsiEZlcXoeg3hsj6ZeUC2mTlcC9zeWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Name = _t, Age = _t, Cyclist = _t, Canoeist = _t, Hiker = _t, Runner = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Age", Int64.Type}, {"Cyclist", Int64.Type}, {"Canoeist", Int64.Type}, {"Hiker", Int64.Type}, {"Runner", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Name", "Age"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Attribute", "Activity"}, {"Value", "Particpates"}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns", each ([Particpates] = 1))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"

Then use Activity in a slicer :





But I thought the question was ANDing the two together, like you'd get with INTERSECT(IsCanoeist, IsHiker) Otherwise, don't the filters effectively return OR(IsCanoeist, IsHiker)?

If you want an OR behaviour allow the multi-selection for the slicers. I updated the answer with the case of Hiker and Runner
